# Using Spring Cloud Gateway and eureka on a Kubernetes deployment

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm working with a system composed of several Spring Boot Microservices and I'm planning on deploying it on Kubernetes.

I'm curious to understand if there would be any advantages in utilizing Spring Gateway and Eureka for service management compared to the services provided directly by Kubernetes.

Thanks!